# Italic in td html tcpdf

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, italic

I use tcpdf using custom font named ProximaNova. I have converted to tcpdf font become 4 fields php proxima.php,proximai.php,proximab.php and proximabi.php

I call font

```
TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('tcpdf/fonts/font-ttf/proxima.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont('proxima', '', 10, '', 'false');
```

The content of td take from database field. The content the field is

```
<i>Text</i>
```

Buat when i use

```
 $html.='<td><span style="font-size:10pt;">'.$res['title'].'</span></td>';
```

the title not italic? Any missing someting? But if i output as html the title become italic.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: dont get `<i>` from database. Do it at time of rendering pdf.

Comment: i have the same issue, have you find a solution?